# Image viewer without smoothing

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, core-graphics

How to create an image viewer for iOS which doesn't do image smoothing when zooming? Like the image viewer of [Screenshots Journal](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/screenshot-journal/id515287854?mt=8).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `NSGraphicsContext` in which your drawing takes place, you can call `[-NSGraphicsContext setShouldAntialias:NO]`.

Comment: This class doesn't seem to be available on iOS.